# How to stop a kid from beating head against things when he's upset?

Tags: toddler, health, aggression

When upset, my 1.5-year-old beats his head against things. He also bangs the back of his head on the floor dropping it once when he falls backward to hit the ground (himself). He's never gotten a bruise.

I'm concerned about damage to his frontal lobes. He's no special needs child in any way that I am aware of, just very emotional.

Comment: What have you tried so far (so that we don't advise you to try something that already failed)? How bad is it? (Has he ever gotten a bruise on the forehead/elsewhere from it? Etc.)

Comment: Have you seen a Dr about this?

Comment: @anongoodnurse No he's never gotten a bruse.  He just does that when he's upset; also when he's upset he'll bang the back on his head on the floor dropping it once when he falls backward to hit the ground (himself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand about this behavior, it is done out of frustration due to not being able to adequately communicate their needs/emotions to others or they feel misunderstood.

At that age, it might be useful to make a "feelings/needs chart" (faces or drawings depicting the emotion/need) and have him point to what he's feeling or what it is he needs. I wish I had more to back this up...

Comment: Young children can often learn sign language before they become verbal. When my son was 1 year old, we took a plane trip. When we got off the plane, he spent a lot of time happily signing "bird" and making car noises.